# MVC resizing on client (bind to model) and upload of image

Tags: c#, javascript, action, asp.net-mvc-5, image-resizing

I have a question regarding the resizing and then sending the image to the controller.

So imagine the following: a user has a upload form where he enters the file and comments to the file and uploads it to the database. The image can be 10mb or 2 mb and so on ... but when the user uploads file on the server side in the action I will resize and maybe crop the image.

this works pretty wel, BUT I don't see the point uploading to the server 10mb and so on if i can resize it on the client side and only upload it after, and i will resize it to more or less 1 or 2 mb.

On client i can resize with javascript (btw anyone can advise me simple, light js library to resize images)?

My question is: how do I upload then the model and the resized file to server?

Because in the form submit i call directly the action and it uploads the file, but I have to make step  in between, and i shouldn't forget that i have to upload a model also, which has some properties and comments.

This is how I do it now:

```
public class ImageModel
{
    public HttpPostedFile File{get;set;}
    public string Comments {get; set;}
}

public ActionResult UploadFile(ImageModel model)
{
    Resize(model.File);
    UploadToDb(model);

    return( new View());
}
```

My biggest question how to bind the output of resized image to the model i postback to the action?
And the good/simple library for the resizing?

Comment: Can anyone elaborate?